# Particle Swarm Optimization Calling Counts

Tags: r, optimization, particle-swarm

While trying to use the `pso` or `hydroPSO` package from R-CRAN, I have a need to use/access the counts (current iteration, current number function evaluation, and current restart) to work with the function I've been writing. However, I can't seem to wrap my head around this.  Any suggestions on figuring out how to call the current iteration/function/restarts within the objective function would be great.  A piece of example code would be appreciated as I seem to fail to fully understand the documentation.

**Background:**
My function requires the iteration number as it is a wrapper to some code written in FORTRAN where the input files are generated and the output files are read back in to R.  I want the iteration number surviving so that I can return back to the previous output files for further analysis. An example of this would be:
`~/runs/<restart #>/<iteration>/<particle>/input/`
`~/runs/<restart #>/<iteration>/<particle>/output/`

The wrapper function accepts the parameters, automatically generates the input files, runs the FORTRAN model, then parses in the output and post-processes them (e.g. performance index calculations).

Comment: You can actually call (compiled) fortran code from R. That should be faster than reading and writing files (these heuristics often do a lot of function evaluations).

Comment: Hey @ErwinKalvelagen, thanks for that comment!  I did look into that option but the way the FORTRAN code I'm using is made that really isn't much of an option for me.  Thanks for that comment though!